# Sorting mysql hours AM PM varchar

Tags: mysql, sorting, while-loop

Sorting problem mysql hours

I have a db with a varchar column

start

with data like (hours)

```
20:15 - 21:30 - 00:15
```

I sort with

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `location_id` = "' . $location['id'] . '" ORDER BY CAST(`start` AS SIGNED) ASC';
```

This gives the following output

```
00:15 - 20:15 - 21:30
```

The problem is I need the 00:15 at last

```
20:15 - 21:30 - 00:15
```

Anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST( substr(start,1,(length(start-6))) AS SIGNED)
```

off the top of my head - no testing..

basic idea - strip off the time part with substring - then do your trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that requirement? 24-hour clock never normally works like that.

Simple hack would be to treat hour 0 as 24:

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE location_id=?
ORDER BY REPLACE(start, '00:', '24:')
```

though any way you do this you're going to lose potential indexability. If you need indexing you'd have to create another column of eg. integer minutes plus 60 modulo 1440.

[Aside: I'd strongly recommend parameterised queries to avoid the potential SQL injection in `location_id`.]

Comment: This looks like an solution but what about 01:15 ect ?

Comment: Found the solution

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `minicms_timetable_event` WHERE `location_id` = "' . $location['id'] . '" ORDER BY IF(LEFT(`start`,2) = "00",1,0), `start` ASC';

Comment: What order do you want `01:15` in? The question doesn't say.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM event WHERE location_id = "' . $location['id'] . '" ORDER BY IF(LEFT(start,2) = "00",1,0), start ASC';
```